# Overheating problem with driver fglrx on ATI radeon h5000 - mobility radeon h4000

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, fglrx, overheating

I have an `HP pavilion dv6-3127 el`, with installed Ubuntu 12.04, i don't use new version of Ubuntu becouse i have overheating problem, temperature about 90 degree, instead in 12.04 i don't have this problem. But, in 04/02/14 i do the updates and after i have overheating problem.

Where i can find the old driver `fglrx`, so i can reinstall in my pc?

Thanks for attention and excuse me for my elementary english. Bye!